# What is the image of the following function

Tags: functions

I have the following function and wanted to find out the image.

The function definition:

\begin{align} p(x)&=\left(x-3\right)^2 \end{align}

The $Domain$ are $[0,5]$ and I came to the results, $image(p)=[9,4]$ but the solution of the book shows me $image(p)=[0,9]$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you just put the endpoints of your domain into $p$. Why do you think that gives you the image? Did you draw a picture of the graph of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

The function is of quadratic form. Quadratics have domain $R$. This quadratic is opening upwards with vertex at (3,0). This should help.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of the function $p(x)=(x-3)^{2}$ is symmetric with respect to the vertical line $x=3$, attains the minimum at $x=3$ with value $0$, and it tends to infinity whenever $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, it increases on $[3,\infty)$, decreases on $(-\infty,3]$, this should help.

Comment: Your explanation definitely makes sense, but I still do not understand how to come to the result.

Comment: You see, so it decreases on $(-\infty,3]$, your domain is $[0,5]$, look at $[0,3]$ this part, the max value must be at $x=0$, which is $9$, look at $[3,5]$, since it increases on $[3,\infty)$, the max value must be at $x=5$, which is 4, compare all of these, the max value is $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that, for $x\in[0,5]$, you have $x-3\in[-3,2]$; conversely, if $x-3\in[-3,2]$, we have $x\in[0,5]$. Thus the question is the same as asking for the image of $g(t)=t^2$ defined over $[-3,2]$.

What is the image of $g(t)=t^2$ over $[-3,0]$? The same as over the interval $[0,3]$, which contains $[0,2]$. So…